# AngularJS prevent ng-blur if button clicked

Tags: angularjs, dom-events, onblur

I have the form - time tracker. And there are several fields, like project, description, time and button "Start timer". From the very start, there is only form and no record in the DB. User can choose Project from the select, then the user has to fill in the field description. To the Description field added `ng-blur` function which creates a new record if it doesn't exist or update if it exists. And button "Start timer" which also has function on `ng-click` which create new record and start timer or update existed record and start/stop timer.

And there is a problem. When User filled in description field **for new record** and he still in this field, and he clicks "Start timer" processed two functions in the same time (ng-blur from description field and ng-click on "Start timer" button). And the system creates 2 the same records (duplicates).

Is it possible to prevent `ng-blur` if "Start timer" button clicked and avoid duplicates.

Comment: While adding a new record you can check previous record for duplicates. Which works for both `ng-blur` and `ng-click` and will eliminate duplicate records.

Comment: @PankajPrakash it is impossible because records can be absolutely identical. It's just time record, and any user can work over the same task multiple times.

Comment: Why does the description need to submit on blur? Why not just have submit on start or enter? It seems like a better User Experience to give them more control over the submit process.

Comment: @georgeawg I see what you mean, and I don't like existing approach at all, BUT it is customer's requirement

Comment: A [blur event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) can't be cancelled and it happens when focus shifts elsewhere, not just upon a click of a button but when focus shifts to another window, frame, tab, or the body of the document. UX designers even discourage using it for validation.

Comment: @OlegSobchuk if that's the case I would suggest maintain a flag and set it to `true` when you add record using `ng-blur`. While adding the record using `ng-submit` check if the flag for blur is not set to `true` then add it, in addition set the flag back to `false` if the record gets added using `ng-submit`.